# NodeJS/C++ addons - Passing an array from node to C++

Tags: node.js

I'd like to pass an array from javascript to C++, however I don't know how to convert the v8 array to a C++ array. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You generally *DON'T*. A C++ app runs in the OS process space; a NodeJS runs in its own virtual space (inside of the "node" process).  Q: How are you calling C++ from NodeJS?  As an "add on", using [require()](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_loading_addons_using_require)?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible code? It'll help others understand how your code's working and provide better answers

Comment: Yes, I am talking about those.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to convert it to JSON which is a platform and language-agnostic string format and pass that to your C++ where it can then parse the JSON string into its own data format.

If your C++ code is running it its now process, you will then have to find a way to deliver the string to the other process.  If the C++ code is in a child process, you can send it over stdio.  If not, then you will need some other interprocess communication mechanism for sending the string to app running the C++ code.

There is a mechanism for creating a nodejs add-on in C++ where you can exchange data between the two and the C++ code runs in the nodejs process, but it is not for the faint of heart as its fairly involved and difficult to learn.  The doc for addons is [here](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html).  It will, in general, be a lot, lot simpler to send a JSON string between two processes.