# Passing array from nodejs to C++ using node addon

Tags: c++, node.js

I previously asked this question and got berated

[NodeJS/C++ addons - Passing an array from node to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66945386/nodejs-c-addons-passing-an-array-from-node-to-c).

However I made it very clear in the question that I want to pass this array from NodeJS to C++ via a C++.

One of the answers was to use JSON, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Why do you need *both* C++ and Nodejs in the first place? Otherwise, "just write your array to a file" would be a general, correct, and very useless answer, but it's impossible to suggest more without knowing context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please checkout this example

[passing array to c++](https://nodeaddons.com/c-processing-from-node-js-part-3-arrays/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `Local<Array>` array, you can simply loop thru it and add all the values to a C++ vector using the `Length()` method that returns the length and the `[]` operator that returns an element on an index. That is probably the fastest way to do it. Using JSON will result in performance drops.